# Change UITableViewCellAccessory after InAppPurchase. Possible?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, in-app-purchase

I've a TabBar Application with 5 tabs. In the fifth tab, I manage the InAppPurchase without problems. When the user buy a content and switch to first Tab (it has a TableView), I would like to change the UITableViewCellAccessory from none to UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator.

It's possibile?

I don't understand where I should insert the change of UITableViewCellAccessory.

Thanks,
Alessandro from Italy.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Alessandro from Italy,

Well the thing you would have to do is to implement the `cellForRow:atIndexPath:` method from the `UITableView` class, in that method you would probably have a conditional of this type:

```
if (IN_APP_PURCHASE_DONE == YES){
    [cell setAccesoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
}
```

Edit:

To be sure you are updating the `UITableVIew`after you purchase the extras, you should check in the `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` method of the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` object when your table view's view controller is going to appear to reload the data.

Comment: Hi El Developer,
thanks for your reply. I've added this code:
if (productPurchased) {
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
} else {
cell.accessoryView = [[ UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lock.png"]];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
}

Not works fine when I switch to First Tab after purchasing. I see always the lock.png;

Comment: I have updated my answer, check for the edit. I think the problem is that the `UITableView` is not reloaded, therefore it keeps the same attributes. Btw if that doesn't work try checking with an `NSLog` that your productPurchased validation is working. Good luck :D

Comment: The `viewWillAppear` method is not called when changing tabs!

Comment: Sorry for that, if you check in the delegate method that I point out in my edit, you should be able to reload the data when the controller is selected.

Comment: Yeah...I've faced and solved this problem before. Instead of `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` you should use `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:`

Comment: Thanks for all. I don't understand how I can fix this bug. I've an AppDelegate.h that contains a `IBOutlet UITabBarController *rootController` and in AppDelegate.m file I've `[self.window addSubview:rootController.view];`
Can i add `tabBarController:didSelectViewController` method in AppDelegate.m file? Or I must set a new class TabBarController with .m and .h files and connect this to rootController? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

El Developer's solution doesn't quite work, because `cellForRow:atIndexPath:` is only executed when the cell is first being created. So if the tab with the tableViewCell is opened before making the in-app purchase, the cell will have been created already, without a disclosure indicator.

Here's what you need to do:

1. In the viewController for the first tab, make a `UITableViewCell` instance variable.
2. In `cellForRow:atIndexPath:` when you create the cell that needs to get the disclosure indicator, set the instance variable to that cell as well.
3. Also in the first viewController, make a method that will add the disclosure indicator to the cell.
4. Call the method above to set the cell's disclosure indicator when the in-app purchase happens. For example, you could make the first tab's view controller the delegate for the fifth tab's view controller.